# Are there zero-width assertions in sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Is it possible to make lookahead or lookbehind zero-width assertions in `sed`? I want to emulate Perl's `(?=)` and family.

My sed is not GNU sed version 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there aren't. You only have [basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03), which only have character sets (`.` and `[…]`), repetition (`*` and `\{m,*n*\}`), line anchors (`^` and `$`) and grouping `\(…\)`, plus backreferences `\N`. Some sed implementations have more repetition syntax (`\+` and `\?`),  alternation (`\|`), additional anchors (`\b`, `\B`, `\<`, `\>`). None that I know of have general zero-width assertions, you need to turn to Perl (or other tools that support PCRE) for that.

Many uses of zero-width assertions can be emulated with general regular expressions, using backreferences. For example, the Perl `s/foo(?=bar)/FOO/` can be written `s/foo\(bar\)/FOO\1/`.

Comment: Backreferences fail if the backreferenced part needs to be matched right after too, though. One point of zero-with matching is that you can still match on those parts separately.