# Is there an equivalent for vim's \zs in sed or perl?

Tags: sed, vim, regular-expression, perl

In vim we can use the `\zs` atom to say "really begin the match right here":

```
:%s/funnyword\zs.*$/otherword/
```

Is there an equivalent for sed or even perl?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Perl (and PCRE) this is achievable with a [zero-width lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(?%3C=pattern)-%5CK):

```
(?<=funnyword).*$
```

which matches "funnyword", but doesn't consume it as part of the match. These only work with fixed-length text in the lookbehind. You can also use negative lookbehinds (`(?<!...)`) to specify that some text isn't there.

In any reasonably recent version of Perl, [`\K` is almost an exact substitute for `\zs`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(?%3C=pattern)-%5CK) as you're using it:

```
funnyword\K.*$
```

`\K` discards everything matched so far but continues matching from that point onwards. The part before `\K` doesn't have to be fixed-length. This is [also in PCRE now](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#resetmatchstart), but I'm not sure what version it came in.

`\ze` can be achieved with a zero-width lookahead instead, using `(?=...)`. That pattern *doesn't* need to be fixed-length.

---

Because sed uses [POSIX BREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03), [there is no lookaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16273/are-there-zero-width-assertions-in-sed). In this case, though, you can fairly easily simulate it using an ordinary capturing group:

```
sed -e 's/\(funnyword\).*$/\1otherword/'
```

You can do the same for positive lookahead. If you really have a more complicated requirement you may have to look to Perl or some other approach.