# sed: Add spaces between letters only

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to insert a space between letters only, not numbers or other characters.

`hello woRLd 12ab34` should become `h e l l o w o R L d 12a b34`

```
sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)\([a-zA-Z]\)/\1 \2/g' file.txt
```

results in `h el lo w or LD 12a b34`

I can't insert a space after every letter, as that doesn't check if the one after that will be a letter also.

I could run the `sed` command twice, which solves the problem but is not elegant. I need to solve this problem using `sed`, if possible.

Comment: Depending on your definition of *letters* and your `locale`, you may want to use `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to run the `sed` command twice, you can simply run the `s`ubstitute command inside the `sed` script twice. `sed` has an elegant way to do this: The empty pattern `//` repeats the previous pattern:

```
sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)\([a-zA-Z]\)/\1 \2/g;s//\1 \2/g' file.txt
```

For the sake of readability, I suggest to use extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])/\1 \2/g;s//\1 \2/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do it using a loop + conditional branch:

```
$ echo "hello woRLd 12ab34" | sed '
:a
s/\([a-zA-Z]\)\([a-zA-Z]\)/\1 \2/
ta
'
h e l l o w o R L d 12a b34
```

or more compactly

```
$ echo "hello woRLd 12ab34" | sed -e :a -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)\([a-zA-Z]\)/\1 \2/' -e ta
h e l l o w o R L d 12a b34
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a single regex using [lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/995714). Unfortunately [`sed` doesn't support lookarounds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16273/44425) so you need to use [perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/44425)

```bash
$ echo "hello woRLd 12ab34" | perl -pe 's/([a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z])/\1 /g'
h e l l o w o R L d 12a b34

$ perl -pe 's/([a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z])/\1 /g' file.txt
h e l l o w o R L d 12a b34
```

Use `perl -pne` if there are multiple input lines to process and `perl -i -pe` to edit the file in-place

Comment: Well Perl, PHP, Python, etc. .... All could solve this problem.

Comment: Or `perl -pe's/\pL\K(?=\pL)/ /g'`