Splitting Words into space separated characters
I have a table with one word in each row. I want to split the word into space separated c h a r a c t e r s. Is there a way to do that via bash command?
If yes, I also have a table with multiple words in each row.
Input:
blind
witt
nakamen
goot 

Output:
b l i n d
w i t t
n a k a m e n
g o o t

Multiword:
Input:
wat Blinns
allens witter
kemen na
se is goot

Output:
w a t B l i n n s
a l l e n s w i t t e r
k e m e n n a
s e i s g o o t


Hi! What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Does this solve your issue? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710800/sed-add-spaces-between-letters-only

What kind of characters? Do you need to be able to handle unicode? Things like ö for example?

@Kusalananda I don't think so. I was about to post my answer there, but realized that the OP of that one only wants to separate alphabetical characters, but not numbers or anything else.

Most, if not all, of the answers you have so far would add a blank character at the end of each output line - is that acceptable or not?

Here's a Perl solution that can also handle Unicode characters:
perl -C -pe 's/\S/$& /g'

I am using this slightly more complicated file as input:
$ cat file
wat Blinns
allens witter
kemen na
se is goot
µëóþäéß©®·

Which gives:
$ perl -C -pe 's/\S/$& /g' file
w a t  B l i n n s 
a l l e n s  w i t t e r 
k e m e n  n a 
s e  i s  g o o t 
µ ë ó þ ä é ß © ® · 

The -p means "read the input file line by line, apply the script given by -e to each line, and then print the resulting line". The -C enables unicode support so we can deal with characters like ö and other non-ASCII multibyte characters. Without it, you would get:
$ perl  -pe 's/\S/$& /g' file
w a t  B l i n n s 
a l l e n s  w i t t e r 
k e m e n  n a 
s e  i s  g o o t 
� � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � 

Then, we are using the substitution operator (s/old/new/) with the global flag to replace all occurrences of the pattern. The pattern is \S which means "any non-whitespace character" and we replace it with itself ($&, on the right hand side of the substitution operator, means "whatever was matched") plus a space.

I believe you'll still have to remove whitespace between words? Possibly first, with s/\h//g ? Thx.

Shorter: s/\B/ /g  ("replace all non-word boundary zero-width points with spaces").

@Kusalananda nice! I had to add -l to the command line flags: perl -C -lpe 's/\B/ /g'

sed 's/[^ ]/& /g' /path/to/file

Add the -i parameter to make changes to the file.

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
~$ raku -ne 'print m:g/\S/ ~ "\n";'     file

#OR:

~$ raku -pe 's:g/\s//; s:g/\S/$/ /;'    file

#OR:

~$ raku -pe 's:g/\s//; s:g/(\S)/$0 /;'  file

Alternatively, using Raku's new comb() routine, or more conventionally with split():
~$ raku -ne '.comb(/\S/).put;'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -ne '.trans(" " => "").split("", :skip-empty).put;'  file

Here are answers coded in Raku, a Perl-family language that features high-level support for Unicode. The first answer simply takes each line and  prints a match to \S non-whitespace characters.
The next two answers are similar to the excellent Perl answer posted by @terdon. Note $/ is how you spell the capture-variable in Raku ($<> also works). For those who dislike "backslash-itis", you can parenthesize to get a numbered capture, and use $0  in the replacement. Should you prefer retaining blanks (spaces) between words, simply delete the s:g/\s//; statement.
The final two answers above uses Raku's comb routine and split routine, respectively. Raku's new comb() routine acts to globally pull out matches to a desired Regex. Raku's comb() operator acts somewhat conversely to split(), letting Raku disallow null Regexes in Raku's split() routine, which hopefully makes Raku code more robust. Note in the final answer, Raku's split() routine still takes a literal "" empty-string.
Sample Input (from @terdon):
wat Blinns
allens witter
kemen na
se is goot
µëóþäéß©®·

Sample Output (all five answers above):
w a t B l i n n s
a l l e n s w i t t e r
k e m e n n a
s e i s g o o t
µ ë ó þ ä é ß © ® ·


Finally, to double-check that you've removed all empty-strings, etc., you can add a call to the raku (or perl) routine, just before output. This will show you Raku's internal representation of the data (each line is a .Seq iterator object):
~$ raku -ne '.comb(/\S/).perl.put;'   file
("w", "a", "t", "B", "l", "i", "n", "n", "s").Seq
("a", "l", "l", "e", "n", "s", "w", "i", "t", "t", "e", "r").Seq
("k", "e", "m", "e", "n", "n", "a").Seq
("s", "e", "i", "s", "g", "o", "o", "t").Seq
("µ", "ë", "ó", "þ", "ä", "é", "ß", "©", "®", "·").Seq


https://docs.raku.org/routine/comb    
https://raku.org

